# Повреждение файлов при отключении питания и исключениях в процессах

Tags: c, windows, файлы, исключения, embedded

Я занимаюсь разработкой автономных систем управления и анализа для тяжелой промышленности. Использую язык C (C99-C11). Очень беспокоит вопрос повреждения файлов и файловых систем, использующихся в Windows (Embedded, CE и пр.) при внезапном обесточивании или при жестком прерывании рабочего процесса/потока, например из-за исключения.

Хотелось бы разобраться в этом вопросе, достойной литературы по этой теме найти не удалось. Посоветуйте что-нибудь, желательно не на английском языке. Или, может быть, кто-нибудь сможет упрощенно объяснить следующее:

1. Ясное дело, если мы открыли файл и пишем в него, и в этот момент происходит отключение питание, или возникает фатальное исключение в одном из потоков процесса, то операция прерывается на полпути. Это практически гарантированно приводит к повреждению файла/файловой системы в том районе, где происходит работа.

   Но ведь даже если мы не работаем с файлом, а в этот момент отключается питание, файл может быть поврежден из-за того, что ОС в фоновом режиме занимается дефрагментацией/индексацией. Это так?
2. Есть ли гарантия, что после возврата управления в программу после функций `fclose()` или `fwrite()` данные гарантированно корректно занесены на носитель?

   Например, ситуация:

   - Процесс имеет два потока, в одном потоке происходит сохранение данных в файл, а в другом возникает ситуация, после которой мы можем лишь завершить процесс. Например, посреди сложной логики malloc() вернул NULL, или отказало устройство, или еще что.

   Я предполагал защитить файл критической секцией, и использовать эту же критическую секцию для инициации аварийного завершения. Тогда, предположительно, после того как работа с файлом закончится, критическая секция освободится, и второй поток сможет в нее зайти и вызвать `abort()` или аналогичную функцию планируемого жесткого прерывания процесса.

   Проблема на мой взгляд в том, что даже после того, как мы сделали `fopen()` + `fwrite()` + `fclose()`, нет гарантий, что файл корректно сохранен, а не гуляет где-то в буферах, которые связаны с нашим процессом.
3. И как контролируется процесс переноса данных из внутреннего промежуточного буфера-кэша жесткого диска на сам носитель?

   Например, файл записан и закрыт, и даже процесс, который все это делал, уже закрыт. Но данные частично или полностью еще находятся во внутреннем буфере-кэше накопителя. Если в этот момент произойдет обрыв питания, то данные, я почти уверен, будут повреждены или уничтожены.

   Как ОС отслеживает перед своим завершением факт того, что данные из буфера накопителя записаны окончательно?

Comment: А аппаратно нельзя поставить UPS, чтобы про внезапное отключение питания забыть?

Comment: @donRumata учитывая грамотность заданного вопроса, думаю, его автора интересуют все таки не UPSы (которые, полагаю, не всегда возможно установить в рамках данной ситуации, так как автор производит софт не для себя), а именно та техническая часть вопроса, о которой он спрашивал)

Comment: ибп не решает всех проблем и всех ситуаций.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, я встречал кучу людей, которые рвут всех в своей области, но плавают в соседних смежных. Именно поэтому я и спросил про чуть другое видение ситуации, потому что ОП мог просто не думать в эту сторону. Опять же, учитывая какая windows открытая операционка и как классно им можно прислать патч через github - проблема может быть (я не прогер, просто предположение) в принципе нерешамемой.

Comment: Образно говоря, проблема и в самом деле является нерешаемой. Слишком много уровней, внутреннее поведение которых неизвестно или сомнительно.

Comment: [Is NTFS fail-safe in case of a power outage?](https://superuser.com/questions/194412)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Но ведь даже если мы не работаем с файлом, а в этот момент отключается питание, файл может быть поврежден из-за того, что ОС в фоновом режиме занимается дефрагментацией/индексацией. Это так?

Во-первых, сомневаюсь, что драйвер самостоятельно будет дефрагментировать что-либо (хотя и не буду утверждать обратное), а отсутствие насущности проблемы фрагментации объясняется в первую очередь грамотными алгоритмами выбора блоков для хранения файлов.

А критические, неустранимые ошибки ФС в таких случаях — это практически невероятный сценарий (скажем, внезапный отказ HDD — куда более вероятен). Но повреждения данных (файлов) с которыми велась активная работа в момент отказа — штатная ситуация.

> 2) Есть ли гарантия, что после возврата управления в программу после функций fclose() или fwrite() данные гарантированно корректно занесены на носитель?

Нет.

- `fwrite ()` гарантирует только занесение данных в пользовательский буфер, но не гарантирует, что эти данные будут переданы ОС. Чтобы принудительно сбросить пользовательский буфер есть функция `fflush ()`. При скоропостижной кончине процесса данные могут быть потеряны.
- `fclose ()` и `fflush ()` сбрасывают пользовательский буфер, но не гарантируют, что  ОС передаст данные на носитель. Если процесс умрёт после их возврата, то изменения не потеряются, но они могут быть потеряны в случае внезапного отключения питания.

> 3) И как контролируется процесс переноса данных из внутреннего промежуточного буфера-кэша жесткого диска на сам носитель?

- Для того чтобы гарантировать запись данных на диск средств Си недостаточно, необходимо пользоваться API ОС. В POSIX-системах (и в linux в частности) есть вызов [`fsync ()`](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=fsync&category=2&russian=0). Он гарантирует, что вернёт управление (само собой без ошибки) только после того как данные физически попадут на диск и переживут внезапный отказ системы. В Win API аналогом [`FlushFileBuffers ()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), согласно документации он сбрасывает системные буферы, но, гарантирует ли сброс буферов самого HDD или нет, я не знаю.

> Как ОС отслеживает перед своим завершением факт того, что данные из буфера накопителя записаны окончательно?

Просто посылает определённую команду HDD. Например, в ATA она так и называется, `FLUSH CACHE`, опкод `E7h`. (здесь должен быть ещё десяток оговорок, которые должны быть интересны только разработчикам драйверов)

Comment: Драйвер может заниматься дефрагментацией, но более вероятно, что дефрагментацией занимается операционная система, учитывая, что данные постоянно пишутся и читаются, даже если мы вот прям совсем ничего не делаем. Проходя через ОС потоки данных разбиваются на кванты, которые так или иначе оптимизируются по очередям для эффективного использования кэшей: дисковых, ОП, процессорных.

Comment: @Максим, не буду спорить т.к. во внутренностях win слабо разбираюсь, а основываюсь только на умозрительных заключениях... если оно действительно есть, то скорей всего это должно быть реализовано отдельной службой (в хрюшке и 2000-й ничего подобного я не замечал); и я подозреваю, что в работе её нет ничего интересного: просто периодический запуск обычного online'ого алгоритма дефрагментации над всей ФС или над отдельными файлами... в любом случае обычная последовательность действий при дефрагментации практически атомарна с точки зрения записи на диск и не должна приводить к сбоям...

Comment: Понял. Значит, если сделать fclose() или fflush(), то после возврата управления из этих функций можно быть уверенным, что последующий вызов abort() не повредит файл?

Comment: @Максим, да, так... кстати, в зависимости от реализации, `abort ()` может сам закрывать файлы с корректным сбросом буферов (но на это не стоит полагаться, в glibc — это так, в win по идее нет).

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

1. Гарантированную запись на диск можно достичь использованием флага `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` при вызове функции `CreateFile()`. Способ имеет два минуса

   1. Замедление операций чтения/записи. Чтобы этого избежать, нужно работать с файлом большими буферами, кратными разделу кластера диска. Альтернативой использования этого флага является функция `FlushFileBuffers()`
   2. Этот флаг гарантирует, что ОС не будет использовать дополнительных буферов, но буферизация есть еще на самом жестком диске. Чтобы отключить буферизацию диска нужно использовать флаг `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH`, но не все устройства этот флаг поддерживают
2. Еще один способ решения проблемы, это писать не в оригинальный файл, а в его копию. А после завершения записи вызывать функцию `ReplaceFile()` и заменять исходный файл.

   В одной системе у меня используется два идентичных файла данных и к каждому файлу в отдельном файле лежит контрольная сумма. Запись файлов идет в такой последовательности:

   1. Запись основного файла
   2. Запись контрольной суммы этого файла
   3. Запись копии
   4. Запись контрольной суммы копии

   По старту системы я считываю основной файл и проверяю его контрольную сумму. Если совпало — работаем. Если нет — эту пару удаляем и проверяем копию.
3. Ну и классическое решение задачи — зеркальный RAID массив

А вообще все упирается в ценность спасаемых данных. В одной системе мы легко можем потерять базу, восстановить ее из чистого бэкапа и работать. А в другой не спасли ни упсы ни рейды. Экскаватор во дворе зацепил силовой кабель и серверная погибла. Правда в саппорте (вроде тогда еще Dell) сказали ничего не трогать, через неделю приехали специалисты и данные подняли.

Comment: а что делать, если вспомогательный файл так же оказался поврежден или вообще отсутствует?

Comment: Учитывая, что запись происходит последовательно, вначале  одной пары, а потом второй, то такое событие маловероятно если вообще возможно. Но у меня, на этот случай, предусмотрено создание файлов на основании текущего состояния системы. Благо бизнес-логика позволяет это сделать в 90% случаев

Comment: ситуация такова, что при резком отключении питания могут повредиться даже те файлы, к которым вы не имеете никакого отношения. А уж что говорить про недавно записанный файл. Ваш вариант снижает вероятность необратимого повреждения, но эта вероятность все равно весьма высока. Что говорить про резервное дублирование, если у меня однажды из-за разрыва питания просто исчез целый раздел диска, безвозвратно, акронис не помог. Хотя я работы с разделом тем не вел.

Comment: С какого перепугу он повредится если к нему никто не обращается?

Comment: Он повредится с такого перепуга, что операционная система может в данный момент заниматься дефрагментацией фоновой, или индексировать файл, или еще чем-то. Внутренняя сложность ОС такова, что этот исход весьма вероятен.

Comment: @Максим, может тогда докинуть сети и реалтаймовой синхронизации с удалённым каталогом?

Comment: @Максим При индексации файл не модифицируется. А дефрагментация сама по себе не запускается

Comment: В общем, суть в том, что файл может повредиться при обесточивании (и не только), даже если мы с ним не работаем. Это факт. Возможно, в мире настольных ПК вероятность этого минимальная, но в мире автоматизации - это регулярная головная боль. Почему это происходит - нужно спрашивать у разработчиков ОС, разработчиков драйверов накопителей и пр. В общем, после достаточного погружения в эту тему, мне стало ясно, что бороться с этим на уровне кода - бессмысленно. Даже рейд-массив, резервные копии и транзакционность проблему не решат, а лишь снизят вероятность ее возникновения.